# The type initializer for 'ClassName' threw an exception

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have a class named 'Utility' which contains several static members. On calling any of those static members, i get an exception 'The type initializer for Utility.cs threw an exception'. I can't figure out what is wrong. Please help!

Comment: Please show the code!

Comment: A `TypeInitializerException` means that the class failed to instantiate. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Read [ask], create a [mcve]. This means a static constructor threw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a static constructor (`static Utility() {...this bit...}`) or a static field initializer (`static SomeType someField = {...this bit...};`) that is failing inside `Utility`. Find out why. You could start by looking at the `.InnerException` of the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: Its not a static class, and I haven't defined any static constructor in the class scope. I am just calling the static members of the Utility class in other classes with the class name.

Comment: @UzairRaza I never said anything about it being a static class; and if you don't have a static constructor, then that leaves: static field initializers. So: check for static field initializers (values on the right of a `=` in a static field declaration), and : look at the `.InnerException`

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much.